Clearing "Recent Connections" from Firefox in KDE Task Bar
So I'm quite new to Linux, Plasma, and openSUSE so forgive my ignorance. I went to type in something rather sensitive and, without my noticing, Firefox popped up and I accidentally typed it into the URL bar. I was actually offline at the time so I'm not worried about whatever I typed being sent over the network but I just can't seem to clear all record of it from my computer. I cleared my browser history immediately but when I right click on the Firefox icon in the task bar on Plasma (openSUSE) I get a list of sites I've recently connected to. What I typed is in there and I just can't get rid of it for some reason.

If I right click there is an option for "Forget Recent Connections" and that clears all of them out except for what I typed and a link to a "plasma-integration" addon for Firefox.
Under ~/.local/share I found recently-used.xbel. The URL I'm trying to remove was in there so I deleted the file and restarted the computer but it was still showing up in the right click menu.
I uninstalled Firefox and removed everything I could find in my home directory that would relate to it, but no luck.

Appreciate any help, if I can't get rid of it soon I'm going to have to wipe my OS, which seems ridiculous just to do something that should be easy.

if it is in the context menu of the taskbar by clicking on firefox, its an desktop applet who saves the recent windows and not firefox. is there a category applet preferences in the context menu. right click on firefox icon. if it is, paste "about". I have Grouped window list (grouped-window-list@cinnamon.org) running.

I was able to reproduce this (seems like a very strange bug), not exactly sure how though, but I got an entry there that didn't wanna go away even after I removed both the plasma-browser-integration and the corresponding Firefox addon.
I removed the following things, rebooted and the entry was gone:

The entry from recently-used.xbel as per the question
The stuff in ~/.cache/bookmarksrunner/
The stuff in ~/.local/share/kactivitymanagerd/

I'm not sure if the last is needed (also, it didn't seem to cause any problem for me, but just in case maybe back it up), but the database was edited at the same time as the recently-used.xbel file and the bookmark cache. You can remove them one by one while rebooting in-between to see which is removes it.
